# Why is there no option to download ubuntu using torrent?

Tags: downloads

Why I cant choose torrent as a download option?

Comment: There's one. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: Why is this off-topic?

Comment: @chaos because it is "not reproducible".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads), it will allow you to download an Ubuntu .torrent file. You need a bittorent client application to download Ubuntu this way.